# keras and shape of input and losses

Tags: keras

In all code examples for keras I see that the input shape is passed directly and it is surmised that the batch size is the first one , eg:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, input_shape=(16,)))
# now the model will take as input arrays of shape (*, 16)
# and output arrays of shape (*, 32)
```

However when it comes to custom losses I see that the last axis (axis=-1) is used.

```
def loss(y_true,y_pred):
        return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
```

When writing the loss should one think of y_true and y_pred as batches or singular samples?
I'm assuming it's the former , but if that's the case I can't understand why it's specifying the last axis

Answer (score 0):

In your custom loss function, you treat `y_true` and `y_pred` as batches which is also the case for the returned value of the function. If you only calculate one loss for your network, you could also get rid of the specified axis, since you only want a single value for your loss in the end.
But if you have multiple outputs in your network and you want to calculate the total loss, where each output might use its own loss functions, things begin to change.

Please check out: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py#L658
where the function to calculate the total loss, `_prepare_total_loss`, is called.
In this function, the following code is executed:

```
output_loss = loss_fn(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=sample_weight)
```

which returns the loss for a single output of your network. This is also where your custom loss function gets called. If there are multiple outputs, all of them are calculated, weighted and added to the total loss: `total_loss += loss_weight * output_loss`

In the end, `_prepare_total_loss` returns `K.mean(total_loss)`. So in the simplest case, if your custom loss function returned a vector with its length equal to the batch size, and there is only one output with loss in your network, the final loss will be the mean of the output-vector returned by your custom loss.
But in case of multiple outputs and multiple losses, you first want to calculate the loss vector of a batch for each output and therefore loss function, take their weighted sum and then calculate the final loss by taking the mean of the resulting vector.
If your loss functions would return a single loss value each instead of a batch-sized vector, the final loss would be the mean of multiple mean loss values which differs from the mean loss of the whole batch.